# Subsetting a sequence excluding numbers < and > x from a vector

Tags: r, vector, subset, subsequence

I am trying to create a new vector C by subsetting all the numbers from a vector A which are smaller than 25 and greater than 75.
My problem is how and where to position the command subsetting the range I want.

```
set.seed(135)
A <- sample(1:100,1000, replace=T)
C <- A[seq(1,length(A),)]
```

I know that I can subset an nth object by putting a number after the last comma like so:

```
B <- A[seq(4,length(AA),4)
```

So I tried to put the range I want to be excluded there but I just get a bunch of errors:

```
Error: unexpected ',' in "C <- A[seq(1,length(A),(x<25,"
> C <- A[seq(1,length(A),x<25,x>75)]
Error in seq.default(1, length(A), x < 25, x > 75) : 
  object 'x' not found
> C <- A[seq(1,length(A),(A<25,A>75))]
Error: unexpected ',' in "C <- A[seq(1,length(A),(A<25,"
> C <- A[seq(1,length(A),A<25,A>75)]
Warning message:
In seq.default(1, length(A), A < 25, A > 75) :
  erstes Element von 'length.out' Argument benutzt
```

I need the first set of the sequence to look like this:

```
[1] 4 93 10 85 8 89 16 91 84 85 ...
```

Comment: Is this what you want: `A <- sample(1:100, 1000, TRUE); A[A < 25 | A > 75]`?

Comment: Yes! 
Thanks a bunch :)
I thought I needed to indicate I want a sequence.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the or operator (`|`) between the conditions.

```
set.seed(135)
A <- sample(1:100,1000, replace=T)
A[A<25 | A>75]
```